# Query to get latest three users, sort by date - Mongoose Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

**This is the data from Mongodb**
(Task.json)

```
    {
        "username": "john",
        "taskId": "001",
        "date": "2020-02-18T20:14:19.000Z",
    },
    {
        "username": "david",
        "taskId": "001",
        "date": "2020-02-18T21:48:19.000Z",
    },
    {
        "username": "john",
        "taskId": "002",
        "date": "2020-02-15T20:20:32.000Z",
    }
    ... many more
```

**What I am trying to acheive**

- I am trying a write a query that returns `taskId` with a list of the
  latest `users` who executed the task (sorted by `date` - descending).
- I only want the last three users who executed the task to show up on the list, thus the `user` array should not contain more the 3 users per task

**Here is an example I created of how I want the response to be:**

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskid": "001",
      "users": [
        {
          "username": "david",
          "date": "2020-02-18T21:48:19.000Z"
        },
        {
          "username": "john",
          "date": "2020-02-18T20:14:19.000Z"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "taskid": "002",
      "users": [
        {
          "username": "john",
          "date": "2020-02-15T20:20:32.000Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**My progress so far:**

```
router.route("/latest-tasks").get((req, res) => {
    Task.find()
        .sort({ date: "desc" })
        .then(doc =>
            res.status(200).json({
                taskId: doc.taskId,
                list: doc.map(doc => {
                    return {
                        username: doc.username,
                        date: doc.date
                    };
                })
            })
        )
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of multi-query scenario here, I suggest you use MongoDB aggregation to do this. This query should work:

```
Todo.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: { taskId: 1, date: 1 }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$taskId",
      users: {
        $push: { username: "$username", date: "$date" }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      taskid: "$_id",
      users: {
          $filter: {
            input: [
              { $arrayElemAt: ["$users", 0] },
              { $arrayElemAt: ["$users", 1] },
              { $arrayElemAt: ["$users", 2] }
            ],
            as: "user",
            cond: { $ne: ["$$user", null] }
          }
        },
    }
  }
]).exec()
.then(doc => { console.log(doc); })
.catch(err => { console.log(err); });
```

Aggregation Pipeline Explanation:

- `$sort`: This sorts the tasks using the taskId and date field in an ascending order
- `$group`: This group the tasks by taskId. This is how we get all users associated with a task
- `$project`: This helps extract just the first 3 users associated with a task. The `$filter` operator used inside this pipeline stage helps to remove null values in case a task does not have up to three users associated with it.

Links: [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/), [Pipeline Stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/), [Pipeline Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

Comment: Thank you, I'll check out the links. I changed sort taskid and date to -1 and it works as I wanted :) Just one thing the response it giving taskId and _id, how do I remove the _id part

Comment: I also see that users returns two arrays (two square brackets), which can be improved

Comment: To remove `_id` in the final result, you can use the `$projection` stage to exclude it. Sorry about the additional square brackets, that was an oversight from my end, to remove that, just remove the first square bracket in `$project.users`. I would update the code snippet to include the two amendments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.aggregate`:

Mongoose code not tested

```
Task.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      taskId: 1,
      date: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$taskId",
      users: {
        $push: {
          username: "$username",
          date: "$date"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      tasks: [
        {
          $sort: {
            _id: 1
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            taskid: "$_id",
            users: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]).exec()
.then( doc => res.status(200).json(doc))
.catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AFxtF7yNGxx)